# AnimationDrawable xml vs dynamically

Tags: android, memory, animated-gif, animationdrawable

I was wondering, is there a difference memory-whise between defining an animationdrawable in xml and making the animationdrawable dynamically in your code?

Comment: no difference,  after all if you define it in xml it has somehow to be created into AnimationDrawable

Comment: I know, but still, xml files are 'static'.. But thanks for the reply!

Comment: what does it mean: static?  see AnimationDrawable sources and find inflate() method,  you will see that addFrame() is used inside for adding every frame definded in xml file

Comment: Ok, if that's the case than you're right.. It's just animation drawables are very slow in loading..

Comment: so copy its code and do custom Bitmap loading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there was no answer I could accept, here is what was said (and what's right).
There is no difference between making an AnimationDrawable in xml or dynamically in code. Android's framework will dynamically create the AnimationDrawable in the background if you made it in xml.